# React Native image replaced with blank "document" image

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

I just upgraded to the most recent version of Xcode, and I am noticing that some of my images are being replaced by blank.. document images? It's hard to describe it, so I included a picture:

[image: Blank document image]

For an example of my markup:

```
<View style={[this.props.styles["card-nav-child-border"]]}>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleCallClick} style={[this.state.cardnavview]}>
        <Text style={this.props.styles["card-nav-text"]}>
            {CallText}{" "}
            <Image style={this.props.styles["card-nav-image"]} source={Call} />
        </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

And my styles:

```
.card-nav-image {
  width: 10;
  height:10;
}
.card-nav-child {
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 250;
}
.card-nav-child-border {
  border-color: #fff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-right-width: 1;
  padding-right: 10;
  padding-top: 5;
  padding-left: 10;
}
.card-nav-child-border-end {
  padding-top: 5;
  padding-right: 10;
  padding-top: 5;
  padding-left: 10;

}
```

I thought maybe it was a sizing thing, but I have tried to artificially increase the size to check, and no luck.

When I removed some random styling it occasionally reverts back.

I'm quite confused by this behavior, and it's difficult to Google as I'm not exactly sure how to describe it even.

I am hoping someone who has had experience with this might be able to provide some information on why it is happening.

If it helps, the images in question are png files

EDIT: It appears to be related to nested  elements?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the most, "React Native" way to fix this problem, or why this problem happened in general, but the fix was this:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleCallClick} style={[this.state.cardnavview]}>
    <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
        <Text style={this.props.styles["card-nav-text"]}>
            {CallText}{" "}
        </Text>
        <Image style={this.props.styles["card-nav-image"]} source={Call} />
    </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```